# Tag Helpers - Razor View asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Visual Studio is not showing intellisense auto-completion for the standard ASP.NET Core tag helpers when editing a Razor View. Can anyone here help me?

[VS 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFGJW.png)

Answer (score 1):

add

```
 @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

to your _ViewImports.cshtml file